# Xamarin Forms switch language at runtime on each page

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm developing a cross-platform app (android, IOS) which has to be able to switch languages on each page at the press of a button. I'm using an AppShell for navigation and have the button for the language switch in the toolbar of the AppShell. I made resource files: AppResources.resx and AppResources.fr.resx. I reload both the current page I am on and the AppShell when switching, which seems to have the side effect of going back to the first page I have set on my navigation bar. The reload of the AppShell seems to be necessary as when I don't do it the page seems to go on top and there is no more navigation as well as the color resources I have set in the AppShell get removed. I use the below code to switch the language of my app:

```
private void Language_switch(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var lang_switch = Lang.Text;
            if (lang_switch == "FR")
            {
                CultureInfo language = new CultureInfo("fr");
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = language;
                AppResources.Culture = language;
                Application.Current.Properties[key: "LanguageCode"] = "fr_FR";
            }
            else
            {
                CultureInfo language = new CultureInfo("");
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = language;
                AppResources.Culture = language;
                Application.Current.Properties[key: "LanguageCode"] = "nl_NL";
            }
            Application.Current.MainPage = new Surveys();
            Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
        }
```

This code used to work but is not working anymore. I do remember updating Xamarin Forms a bit ago so this might have something to do with the code not working anymore. In XAML I read from the resource files as below:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyOpinion.Views.Surveys"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyOpinion.ViewModels"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             xmlns:resource="clr-namespace:MyOpinion.Resx">

<Label Text="{x:Static resource:AppResources.Openstaande}" TextColor="{StaticResource Text}" FontSize="24" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: why are you doing this  Application.Current.MainPage = new Surveys();
            Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();

Comment: this is to reload the Surveys page and the AppShell. Is there another way of doing this? as just doing the language switch doesn't seem to change any of the labels and only switches in the backend as far as i understand

Comment: Dear You need just to load one page either appshell or surveys. if you want to only navigate to Surveys after changing the lang then delete  Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();

Comment: Yes this works and switches the language. But if I don't reload the AppShell it seems to go back to standard color with only the elements I have given a color myself being in the color they should be. The navigation at the bottom of the page disappears and the toolbar at the top turns a different color as well.

Comment: Okay so i understand you want to change the language then navigate to Surveys page. Do this : Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell(); await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Surveys() );

Comment: well the best would be it stays on the same page as it is being switched on. which its doing now with only the page reload. the problem with that ends up being that the colors are wrong after switching and that the navigation of the AppShell disappears

Comment: from what i have been able to find is that when you navigate like this it removes the navigation for some reason. is there a way to reload the page without it removing the navigation?

Comment: Ofcourse your navigation stack is removed when resetting the MainPage, because it resets the stack. As far as I know there's no way to switch language at runtime without popping to the root because the bindings of the pages that are already on the stack will not fire for the new Culture change. Your best bet is to 'save' the stack, reset MainPage and navigate back to where your user left off.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the TranslateExtension provided from Xamarin Community Toolkit. You don't need to reload your pages.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             x:Class="MyLittleApp.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>

        <Label Text="{xct:Translate AppResources.ATranslatedMessage}" />

        <Label Text="{xct:Translate AppResources.AnotherTranslatedMessage, StringFormat='#{0}'}" />

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

You should Initiliaze it first:

```
LocalizationResourceManager.Current.PropertyChanged += (_, _) => AppResources.Culture = LocalizationResourceManager.Current.CurrentCulture;
LocalizationResourceManager.Current.Init(AppResources.ResourceManager);
```

After Language change you call:

```
LocalizationResourceManager.Current.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
```

Here is documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/extensions/translateextension

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/helpers/localizationresourcemanager

Answer (score 0):

As @Michael said i dont think either there is a way to change language without poping to Root. Though i dont recommend his idea of copping the navigation stack then pushing the pages. But i will implement the idea for you.
Note that navigation stack in readonly property.

```
 
var navStack = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack;
Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.RemovePage(navStack.First());

Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell ();
foreach (var item in navStack)
{
   await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.GetType()));
}
```